# React component + jQuery draggable thinks every element is the same object

Tags: jquery-ui, reactjs, es6-class

*Disclaimer: React noob over here - I apologize if I'm bastardizing the way it's meant to be used.*

I'm trying to use jQuery's draggable API in conjunction with React components. However, whenever I drag the list item, the object associated to the drag event is the same.

```
class CompanyListItem extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    that = this
    $("[role='draggable']").draggable({
        start: (e, ui)=> {
          that.props.dragHandler(event, ui, this);
        },
        revert: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li className="draggable company" id={this.props.company.id} role="draggable">
        <span>{this.props.company.name}</span>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

class CompanyList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var rows = []

    _.each(this.props.companies, (company) => {  
      rows.push(<CompanyListItem company={company} dragHandler={this.props.dragHandler} key={company.id}/>);
    });

    return (
      <ul> Select
        {rows}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

For example, the component rendered below:

[image]

The object tied to both list elements is the "HopShop" (the first rendered list item)

Comment: just curious have you considered not using jquery and using one of the react draggable libraries instead?

Comment: @DominicTobias - I have not.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call `$("[role='draggable']").draggable(...)` you reset the other components. You should call it on the id instead.

```
componentDidMount() {
    that = this
    $("#" + this.props.company.id).draggable({
        start: (e, ui)=> {
          that.props.dragHandler(event, ui, this);
        },
        revert: true
    });
}
```